# Using a Try catch to get a clean error message

Tags: apex, trigger

Hi and thanks in advance for any help...

I want to get a clean custom error message.  I read that using a try catch would help.  Would I put the try before the second 'For' loop, or right before the "if" statement?

Here is my code.

```
trigger stopDuplicateRegRequest on Registration_Requests__c (before insert, before update) {
    Map<String, Registration_Requests__c> regMap = new Map<String, Registration_Requests__c>();
    Map<String, Registration_Requests__c> regMap1 = new Map<String, Registration_Requests__c>();    
    Map<Boolean, Registration_Requests__c> regMap2 = new Map<Boolean, Registration_Requests__c>();

    for (Registration_Requests__c regReq : System.Trigger.new) {
                // store registration Request pertinent values
                regmap.put(regReq.Account__c, regReq);
                regmap1.put(regReq.Product__c,regReq);           
                regmap2.put(regReq.Duplicate_Registration__c,regReq);  

    //Loop through and make sure no duplicates exist
    //fields are Account, Product and Status != 'Closed'  

    for (Registration__c reg : [SELECT Account__c,Product__c, Registration_Status__c, Duplicate_Registration__c FROM Registration__c])
 {
   If (regReq.Duplicate_Registration__c == False && reg.Registration_Status__c != 'Closed' && reg.Account__c == regReq.Account__c && reg.Product__c == regReq.Product__c )
      {
      regReq.addError('Registration for this Product already exists. If you want to enter it anyway, check the "Account has multiple locations" checkbox'
                       + ' and fill out the Location field');
      break;                 
       }// end if

} //end for (Registration__c reg 
}//for (Registration_Requests__c

       }//end trigger
```

Comment: The `addError` method you are using is a normal approach: what are you hoping to gain by adding try/catch? Note that you should move the query of `Registration__c` out of the loop (especially as the query will always return the same results) to avoid hitting a governor limit when many `Registration_Requests__c` are modified at once.

Comment: try catch becomes more helpful when used in a controller action method that does DML on `Registration_Requests__c`

Comment: also - (1) your duplicate checking logic won't catch duplicate registrations within the same trigger set and (2) if you have thousands of registrations, the for loop may hit CPU governor limits.  Why not look at OOB Duplicate Management feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've been told in comments, a try-catch block isn't an appropriate solution for the situation you're trying to handle. Let's first take a closer look at your trigger and help you with the logic of how to rewrite it to identify duplicates without doing SOQL inside a FOR loop.

```
trigger stopDuplicateRegRequest on Registration_Requests__c (before insert, before update) {

    //If you want to use maps, its important that the map keys be unique, so let's use 
    //Registration_Requests__c from trigger.new as the key & the object field as the value

    Map<Registration_Requests__c, String> regMap = new Map<Registration_Requests__c, String>();
    Map<Registration_Requests__c, String> regMap1 = new Map<Registration_Requests__c, String>();    
    Map<Registration_Requests__c, Boolean> regMap2 = new Map<Registration_Requests__c, Boolean>();
    Boolean DupReg = false;

    for (Registration_Requests__c regReq : System.Trigger.new) {

                // store registration Request pertinent values
                regmap.put(regReq, regReq.Account__c);
                regmap1.put(regReq ,regReq.Product__c);

                //regmap2.put(regReq, DupReg);  
                //we shouldn't need to populate the last unless a dupe is found. 
                //There's also no need to add a field on your object for this  

    }//end for (Registration_Requests__c regReq

    //query for registrations that only contain accounts and products in our maps with Status != closed
    list<Registration__c>reg : [SELECT Account__c,Product__c, Registration_Status__c FROM Registration__c WHERE Account__c IN : regmap.values() AND Product__c IN : regmap1.values() AND Registration_Status__c != 'Closed']);

    //Loop through and make sure no duplicates exist

    for(Registration_Requests__c rgRq : Trigger.new){
        for(Registration__c rg : reg){
            if(rgRg.Account__c == rg.Account__c && rgRg.Product__c == rg.Product__c){
                DupReg = true;
                regMap2.put(rgRg, DupReg);
                //can put into map here as shown above or can 
                //put addError message code here instead as below: 

                //regReq.addError('Registration for this Product already exists. If you want to enter it anyway, check the "Account has multiple locations" checkbox'
                //    + ' and fill out the Location field');
             }

        }//end for(Registration__c rg

    }//end for(Registration_Requests__c rgRq

    if(regMap2.isEmpty() == false){

        // if you didn't insert your addError logic in the main loop (purpose of the trigger)
        // this is where you'll want to do it if the map isn't empty 

    }// end if

}//end trigger
```

**Discussion**

As you can see from your modified code, we really didn't need maps at all and could have used lists or sets (even better) to collect the `Account__c` and `Product__c` values needed for the query. We were also able to eliminate needing to test for `Registration_Status__c != 'Closed'` by including that condition as part of our query. I want to add a caveat that doing the latter can be problematic in a very large database. It's not very efficient to query for a `!=` condition via SOQL as opposed to searching for a match.

I recommend you look at the [addError Method Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError). You don't want to put a break in your code after you find a duplicate. You want your code to process all of the records from your users and find all errors from trigger.new before it exits the loop. There could be additional duplicate records that need to be found and displayed to other users before exiting. You'll have missed those if you exit prematurely.

This code illustrates that we break code up for specific purposes or functions/tasks. Not everything needs to be done in one large for loop. That can be very ungainly and cumbersome. Often its best to identify and collect the records you need first and work with those instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  I will definitely be cleaning up my code based on suggestions.

Comment: You're welcome @user4012. Community etiquette is to help others by marking your question as solved through checking the answer that resolved your issue. If you don't, it leaves the impression to anyone who searches the topic later that your question wasn't answered to your satisfaction. Once you have sufficient reputation, you can also upvote questions and answers.